# Testing / Improving Performance of Multithreaded Program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to throuougly test the performance of a program, and in particular a multi-threaded program.  In particular, using Visual Studio 2010, how can I test:

1. What parts of my code are taking the longest
2. What parts of my code are not necessary

Etc.  Any thoughts are much appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: VS2010 has a parallel performance profiler. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010debug

Comment: @EricLaw IMO you should add that as an answer

Comment: I hope you haven't written a substantial program and are doing multi-threaded testing at the end! Sorting out threading issues at the end  isn't going to be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a built-in profiler that does a pretty good job actually. I've got VS 2010 Ultimate installed so I'm not sure which version its all supported in but you can get to it from the Analyze menu. Some of the options are CPU Sampling, function counts and timing, memory allocation and concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ 
It offers a free 10 day trial if you are looking to use it right away and don't want to put up the $ for it.

Answer (score 1):

*Thoroughly* test a multi-threaded program?

Release it to the users.